# Iterating over a List of nested objects and storing them into a HashMap using Stream API

Tags: java, java-8, hashmap, java-stream

I am trying to iterate over nested java object and from nested object I'm trying to populate a *map* using Java 8.

Here is the list and structure of objects

`IssueTypeDto.java`

```
public class IssueTypeDto {
    private String id;
    private String name;
    private List<CustomFieldDto> customFields;
}
```

`CustomFieldDto.java`

```
    private String id;
    private TypeDto type;
```

I am getting `List` of `IssueTypeDto` as response. Each `IssueTypeDto` object can have a list of `CustomFieldDto` objects. My requirement is I need to iterate over a list of `IssueTypeDto` objects and for each `CustomFieldDto` object I need to get `id` and the corresponding `TypeDto` object and insert it into a map as key and value. Here is what I am trying to do currently

```
Map<String, TypeDto> map = issueTypes.stream()
    .flatMap(issueType->issueType.getCustomFields().stream()
                .collect(Collectors.toMap(
                            CustomFieldDto::getId,
                            CustomFieldDto::getType)));
```

But i am getting compile time error as Type mismatch:

```
cannot convert from Stream<Object> to Map<String,TypeDto>"
```

I am new to Java 8 streams. So I am not able to figure out the issue. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's know the general concepts. You want to transform one object to another one. It can be 1 to 1 relationship or 1 to many. In case of 1 to 1 you need to use .map. 1 to many - .flatMap. So in other words map convert Object A to Object B. flatMap convert Object A to Stream of Object B. You was near you missed ')'.

Your case should be like this:

```
issueTypes.stream()
.flatMap(issueType -> issueType.getCustomFields().stream())
.collect(Collectors.toMap(CustomFieldDto::getId CustomFieldDto::getType));
```

Also please be sure that there are no duplicates on keys of different objects, otherwise Collectors.toMap() will throw exception due to key duplication.

Comment: You can add as the third argument to `toMap` a BinaryOperator to handle duplicate keys, see: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#toMap-java.util.function.Function-java.util.function.Function-java.util.function.BinaryOperator-

Comment: @WJS I found the solution. I wanted to keep first one encountered. Thank you

Comment: @Stanislau Kozel. Thanks for the solution. I was trying to understand your comment. So the code which i posted does it give multiple stream of objects or map as output? Just trying to understand the difference

Comment: @SachinHR 
Your code tries to produce a stream of Maps.
Stream<Map<String, TypeDto>> is your generic output from post.

Comment: @StanislauKozel The stream from the original code can't be inferred as a stream of maps `Stream<Map<String,TypeDto>>` because it will not compile, the type of function passed to the `flatMap()` doesn't match.

Comment: @AlexanderIvanchenko Yea, it is original issue...

Answer (score 2):

The code you've provided does not compile for two reasons:

- [`flatMap()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Stream.html#flatMap(java.util.function.Function)) is an *intermediate* operation which expects a function that returns a **stream** as an argument. Instead, you've created a nested stream that generates a *map*. Therefore, your function doesn't match what `flatMap()` expects.
- Your stream pipeline lacks the *terminal* operation, therefore this assignment is incorrect

```
Map<String, TypeDto> map = issueTypes.stream().flatMap();
```

There's a map on the left side and a stream on the right side (because `flatMap()` is an *intermediate* operation, returns you stream).

To fix it, you need to make the function passed into the `flatMap()` return a stream, and add a *terminal* operation to the pipeline, i.e. produce the result from the main stream by moving `collect()` out from the `flatMap()`.

That's how it can be done by using `Collectors.toMap()` *(in the comments you've mentioned that there could be duplicated* `id`s ):

```
Map<String, TypeDto> map = issueTypes.stream()
    .flatMap(issueType -> issueType.getCustomFields().stream())
    .collect(Collectors.toMap(
        CustomFieldDto::getId,   // mapping a key
        CustomFieldDto::getType, // mapping a value
        (left, right) -> left    // resolving duplicates - preserve the first encountered value
    ));
```

Another way of handling duplicates is preserve all of them by storing values mapped to the same key into a list, which can be done with `Collectors.groupingBy()`:

```
 Map<String, List<TypeDto>> map = issueTypes.stream()
    .flatMap(issueType -> issueType.getCustomFields().stream())
    .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(CustomFieldDto::getId));
```